# How to quickly view the folder location of currently selected file open in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ for the explorer panel to reflect the location of the current file that is being focused on (i.e. when you click on a file from the Doc Switch Panel, make the explorer panel display the origin of that selected file on the fly)?

Is there anything like this that can be done in Notepad++?

I'm finding that I have to "dig" my way through the explorer panel just to get back to the original folder location of some files that may be open in my Doc Switch panel.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you click on the `>>` in the explorer bar, you'll see an option `Folder of current file`. This may help, but needs a click

Comment: Thank you! I can't  believe I missed that. There is a folder icon in the current version of Notepad++, when clicked, does exactly what you explain.  Thanks again.

Comment: @blackhawk I'm glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

also if you dont want permanent display you can simply mouseover on the tab with the document's name. it displays the full path.

Answer (score 0):

The context (right click) menu on the file's tab provides options for copying the file name or the directory or both (ie the full file path) to the clipboard.

Checked in Notepad++ v6.3.2.