# How can i create quick access to my file in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have notepad++ 7.2

How i can create quick access, something like browser bookmark to open fast favorite file

also i use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016029/how-to-quickly-view-the-folder-location-of-currently-selected-file-open-in-notep) but don't work for me

thank you

Answer (score 18):

*View-->Project-->ProjectPanel1*

Right-click on Workspace and choose *Add New Project*

Give it any name you like, then right click on the new project and select *Add Files*.  Add the file (or files) you want to have easily available to your new project.

Save the workspace.

Now you can easily open any of the files there by double-clicking on them.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/561667/notepad-file-bookmarks-working-like-web-page-bookmarks-in-web-browser) question with Explorer plugin recommended. Also there was [npp favorites](https://github.com/heldersepu/nppfavorites) plugin, but it seems not to be available in plugin manager.

Answer (score 2):

[I just replied the same question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/561667/notepad-file-bookmarks-working-like-web-page-bookmarks-in-web-browser/1646132#1646132).

I use the customizable "Run" menu of Notepad++ as a sort of bookmark location.

You add items to the Run menu by editing the `shortcuts.xml` file inside the `<UserDefinedCommands>` tags. For example, to add that file itself as a bookmark, you would have:

```
<UserDefinedCommands>
    <Command name="Modify shortcuts.xml file" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml</Command>
</UserDefinedCommands>
```

This way you can add any file as bookmark. You only need to prefix it with `$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe`  (or equivalently `$(NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH)`) if the file format has a different default application to open it than Notepad++. Otherwise, just write `...Key="0">C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml</Command>`. If the file path includes spaces, you need to wrap it in quotes.

As you can guess, this means that you can add other programs as bookmarks as well. E.g. I have a bookmark to edit the config file of a program on Notepad++; right below that, I have an entry for an executable to force the config changes to that program to take effect. The latter (executing other programs) is presumably the intended purpose of `<UserDefinedCommands>`; I just use it to add Notepad++ file bookmarks as well.

As you can observe from the syntax, you can add keyboard shortcuts to your bookmarks as well. This is more convenient to do from the Shortcut Mapper rather than editing the file, in order to avoid having to lookup key codes. But I usually don't bother with adding custom keyboard shortcuts; all the bookmarks are accessible using the regular access keys, without having to remember anything. E.g. for the bookmark above, I press `Alt + R` and then `M` to open shortcuts.xml. If you want to use a letter other than the first letter of the `Command name` you typed, you can specify that letter with `&`, e.g. `Command name="Modify &shortcuts.xml`, which will be underlined in the menu.

More info about adding items to Notepad++ Run menu is at [Notepad++ User Manual - Configuration Files Details](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#userdefinedcommands).